# using Automator to paste selected text to a word document

Tags: text, copy, applescript, paste, automator

I want to make an Automator shortcut to paste selected text to a Word document.

1. To provide Applescript with the selected text I used the following code:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set input to input as text
    set the clipboard to the input as string
    return input
end run
```

2. Then I "Get" and "Open" a specified Word document
3. And here, as I understand it, a new Applescript with the function "paste selected text to this word document" should be, but I have some real problems with this part of the Automator algorithm. Could anyone please help and/or give any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: What else are you doing that the regular copy/paste key/menu isn’t enough?

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do here is actually to work as effectively as possible with a text, or rather with new words in it. This automator function should be an instrument to "collect" words and phrases in one place as fast as possible, while continuing reading the text itself. The regular never-ending manual copy/paste key/menu algorithm could be pretty time-consuming in this case,  especially when the list of words gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: So the thing is I want to use this script repeatedly, many, many times -- when put that way, I believe, the purpose of the script is clearer.

Comment: The regular clipboard doesn’t work like that - each copy replaces the current contents.  Are you talking about something like a quick action to _append_ the current text selection to a _file_ or _open document_?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I'm looking for! (for some reason I thought clipboard could be successfully used for this purpose as a temporal container for the selected text, so after the current text selection is finally appended clipboard can be then overwritten with the new text selection, and so on and so on -- at least that was my line of thought)

Comment: So, if trying to explain it again, I have a blank Word document and some text with parts of it that I want to quickly select and transfer to this blank word document  w/ one shortcut (ideally using some formatting pattern). Example: 1) A text in foreign language. 2) A word document with new vocabulary transferred using this presumed "quick action" from the text. Something like that.